# Notepad++ and regex with removal of unmatching sections

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm using this regex string I've crafted...

```
['"]{1}\w+@\w+\.{1}\w\w\w?['"]
```

To hunt for email addresses contained in quotes in an old badly formatted legacy file.

Example:

```
 ADF325@#%jkdaf-@#%j-afd(#$w52'leroyjenkins@myguild.edu'@#%kladfjkla-235dsaf-'thisemail@example.com'2l35jk2dz-dl1jkozf-afajelj'gooselick@somebodyspastries.co'l2#%Jk23l5jlafafljewo8972509357
j2k3l5jadfjeljwfoobar'foobar@barfoo.foo'jk23j-zv8902354jlfa
('352lj53k2ljkumquat'fakeemail@realemail.wtf')lajflsdf
etc.
```

The regex is working beautifully for me... except for one thing. I want to replace everything that -doesn't- match with whitespace so I can work on formatting this to migrate this to the proper DB. How can I delete everything that doesn't match (and preferably, throw a newline between each match)?

Comment: If you want to catch emails to put them in a db table, why don't you use php with `preg_match_all`? I don't see any reason to use npp to do that.

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
['"](\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})['"]|(?s).
```

and replace with `(?{1}\1\n)`.

A bit faster equivalent ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZaiP5y/1)):

```
['"](\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})['"]|[^'"]*(?:['"](?!\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3}['"])[^'"]*)*
```

**Details**

- `['"]` - a quote
- `(\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})` - Group 1: 1+ word chars, `@`, 1+ word chars, `.` and then 2 or 3 word chars
- `['"]` - a quote
- `|` - or
- `(?s).` - any single char.

If Group 1 matches (`(?{1}`) the match is replaced with the Group 1 contents (`\1\n`). If the `(?s).` matches, the match gets removed.

[image]

Comment: Tried it, it just crashes notepad++.

Comment: @liljoshu Do not try it, *use* it. See my settings window with sample replacement results.

Comment: Looks like it may be crashing just due to the size of file it's trying to parse. I'll split it up into chunks and attempt use again.

Comment: @liljoshu [This regex variation](https://regex101.com/r/ZaiP5y/1/) will be faster. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Sweet, it's not crashing notepad++... slowing my system down and taking forever to process, but not crashing (the file is fairly large). I'll be giving this correct answer vote once its done chewing through everything, assuming it worked, which I'm guessing it will at this point.

Comment: Still had to break the file into parts, but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

When you have to deal with large files, the way to process them consists to not load them entirely. Instead you have to read them as a stream. You can't do that using npp, but it's possible using a script language like php.
If you want to make changes or to extract something in particular when you load a file as a stream, you can write a user-defined stream filter:

```
class EmailFilter extends php_user_filter
{
    public function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
    {
        while ( $bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in) ) {
            if ( preg_match_all('~\'\K\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3}(?=\')|"\K\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3}(?=")~S', $bucket->data, $matches) ) {
                 $bucket->data = implode("\n", $matches[0]);    
            }
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
}

stream_filter_register('email_filter', 'EmailFilter');
$handle = fopen('php://filter/read=email_filter/resource=yourfile.txt', 'rb');

while (feof($handle) !== true) {
    echo fgets($handle); 
}

fclose($handle);
```

When you adopt this kind of approach, nothing forbids to insert mails in your table five by five, ten by ten, twenty by twenty or the number you want. The goal is to not load all the file in memory.

*(more examples in O'Reilly Modern PHP)*

Comment: Already succeeded with the other solution after breaking the file into parts (it's a one-off situation), but your answer is really good especially if I would have had to do it repeatedly.

Comment: @liljoshu: The main advantage is the low memory foot-print. Even if you have to do it once, but due to the file size, your system is on the knees, this will take many time.

Comment: Because it seemed a good item (and because I'm a PHP coder as well), I decided to give your script a try... turns out it returns the whole line with the email address, and not just the email, so it resulted in output near identical to the input.

Comment: @liljoshu: you missed something, because I get exactly: `leroyjenkins@myguild.edu
thisemail@example.com
gooselick@somebodyspastries.co
foobar@barfoo.foo
fakeemail@realemail.wtf` nothing more nothing less.